# How to configure a Sublime Build System for TypeScript

Tags: sublimetext2, typescript

I'm looking to configure a Build System in Sublime Text for TypeScript.

I'm currently using...

```
{
  "cmd": ["tsc", "$file"],
  "selector": "source.ts"
}
```

I'd also like to set the 'file_regex' property to handle error messages.

Anyone know what to set this to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this on OS-X:

```
{
    "cmd": ["tsc","$file"],
    "file_regex": "(.*\\.ts?)\\s\\(([0-9]+)\\,([0-9]+)\\)\\:\\s(...*?)$",
    "selector": "source.ts",
    "osx": {
       "path": "/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin"
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the Sublime Build System created for Windows. Tested and working as expected. However you need to include tsc.cmd path in the windows environment, otherwise you should define the root to the Typescript command in the `cmd` section below:

```
{
    "cmd": ["tsc","$file"],
    "file_regex": "(.*\\.ts?)\\s\\(([0-9]+)\\,([0-9]+)\\)\\:\\s(...*?)$",
    "selector": "source.ts",

    "windows": {
        "cmd": ["tsc.cmd", "$file"]
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you keep getting a an error like so?: ```[Errno 2] No such file or directory```

Comment: @Diogenes Then you are probably using ST3 and should use "shell_cmd" instead of "cmd"

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions now. This [one](http://blog.hugeaim.com/2012/10/03/build-typescript-with-sublime-text-2/), or this [one](https://gist.github.com/3814020). Creating your own is easy, by referring to this [document](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build).