# How can I parse error messages from TypeScript in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, typescript

I am trying to setup a Sublime Text 2 build system for TypeScript. I have followed the directions I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779631/how-to-configure-a-sublime-build-system-for-typescript). Actually calling out to the compiler works, however it does not pick up the error messages correctly.

Here is my sample TypeScript program:

```
function greeter(person: string) {
     return "Hello, " + person;
}
var user = "Jane User";
document.body.innerHTML = greeter(us-er);
```

When I compile from the command line, I see the following output:

> C:/data/helloworld.ts(5,34): The name 'us' does not exist in the
>   current scope C:/data/helloworld.ts(5,37): The name 'er' does not
>   exist in the current scope C:/data/helloworld.ts(5,26): Supplied
>   parameters do not match any signature of call target

When I build from within Sublime Text 2 I see the following output:

> C:/Data/helloworld.ts(5,34): [Finished in 0.6s]

I have tried different variations of the file_regex, as mentioned in the original question, all with the same result. My current version of the file looks like:

```
{
    "selector": "source.ts",
    "cmd": ["tsc.cmd", "--target","ES5", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(.+?)\\(([0-9]+,[0-9]+)\\)\\: (.+)$"
}
```

When I test the regex using the [Python Regex Tool](http://www.pythonregex.com/) this version matches the 3 parts correctly. However, Sublime Text refuses to show me the actual error message.

Can anybody point out what I am doing wrong?

It is very frustrating, especially as the one site even shows an example of Sublime Text correctly displaying the error message.

This is with Sublime Text 2.01 64-bit on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the process is terminated before the output buffer is flushed. You could verify this with:

```
{
    "selector": "source.ts",
    "cmd": ["tsc.cmd", "--target","ES5", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "(.*)"
}
```

You should still only get something like

```
C:/Data/helloworld.ts(5,34): [Finished in 0.6s]
```

---

To solve this problem, you could try to put some delay into the batch-file `tsc.cmd`:

```
@echo off
:: Run the compiler
node "C:\typescript\tsc.js" %*

:: Waits for 500ms
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 500
```

**EDIT:**
See Markus' comment about using Windows Script Host instead of node. This fixes the problem. Further research suggests this is actually a known issue with node on Windows: see [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3479) and [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3584).

Comment: Thanks for the tip Markus. I tried what you suggested, but the result is basically the same. It now looks like:  "C:/Data/helloworld.ts(5,34): 
C:\Data>SilentWaiter 2000 
Done waiting!
[Finished in 2.7s]" - I am out of ideas of what to try next :-(

Comment: What javascript engine are you using? Could you call it directly? Could you try another one?

Comment: I am using nodejs, "node -v" displays "v0.8.14". This is the official Windows install from the nodejs.org web site. It appears to be 64-bit as well. What other options do I even have?

Comment: It should work. Try calling it directly, instead of trough `tsc.cmd`. If nothing works, you could try Windows Scripting Host: `cscript //NoLogo tsc.js --target ES5 yourfile.ts`

Comment: Thanks Markus, using Windows Scripting Host fixed the problem. Turns out it is a known issue with node on Windows. I updated your answer to include this info and accepted it.