# Java can't get full error when running an external command

Tags: java, process, cmd

I'm trying to compile [typescript](http://typescriptlang.org) files in java.

Here is a ".ts" file which has errors:

```
alert("hello, typescript");
errrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrror
```

When I compile in windows shell(cmd):

```
tsc hello.ts
```

It will report error with message:

```
E:/WORKSPACE/test/typescripts/hello.ts(2,0): The name 'errrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrror' 
does not exist in the current scope
```

But when I do it in java:

```
String cmd = "cmd /C tsc hello.ts";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
String out = IOUtils.toString(p.getInputStream());
String error = IOUtils.toString(p.getErrorStream());
System.out.println("### out: " + out);
System.out.println("### err: " + error);
```

It prints:

```
### out:
### err: E:/WORKSPACE/test/typescripts/hello.ts(2,0):
```

You can see the detail errors is not captured. Where is wrong with my code?

---

**update**

I just made sure that the `tsc.exe` provided by MS has no such problem, and the one I run in this question is the `tsc.cmd` installed from npm `npm install typescript`

Comment: Give a try to apache [common exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) and i think that should help you out.

Comment: I'm afraid it's a problem of the compiler `tsc` of typescript. Since I tried some tools(grunt.js) other than Java, they can only get the first line of error message too.

Comment: I just made sure that the `tsc.exe` provided by MS has no such problem, and the one I run in this question is the `tsc.cmd` installed from npm `npm install typescript`

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401598/how-can-i-parse-error-messages-from-typescript-in-sublime-text-2

Comment: If it helps, here's a project that does typescript compilation from java: https://github.com/martypitt/typescript4j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a raw Process/ProcessBuilder combination?

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd /C tsc hello.ts");

//merge error output with the standard output
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process p = pb.start();
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I was really wondering, why there wasn't a solution using BufferedReader

Comment: When I try this solution, it introduce another error, which I can't handle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535155/how-to-let-java-output-english-errors-instead-of-other-languages

Comment: You need to replace "UTF-8" by the encoding of CMD.

Comment: See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348811/get-list-of-processes-on-windows-in-a-charset-safe-way

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a couple hours chasing the same problem.

In the end I worked around it by adding `"2> errorfile.txt"` to my command line. This redirects the `stderr` to a file and then I read and print that file.