# How to let java output English errors instead of other languages?

Tags: java, localization

My system is Chinese, and when there is an error occurs in my java program, it may output non-English error messages which is unreadable:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, 系统脮也禄碌陆指露
```

or:

```
IOException occured : Cannot run program "cmd /C tsc hello.ts": 
CreateProcess error=2, ϵͳÕҲ»µ½ָ¶
```

Is it possible to let java always output English error messages ?

Comment: Do you need the rest of Java to believe that the system locale is Chinese, or are you happy for it *all* to become English?

Comment: If I can just make the error message to be English, that would be best. But if it's not possible, it's fine to make everything English

Comment: Are other exceptions in Chinese as well, or is it *just* when you're creating a process? I wonder whether this error message is actually coming from the operating system. (Your second error looks like it's being incorrectly displayed due to an encoding error, btw.)

Comment: They are the same message, the first one is copy from "cmd" console, the second is from web page. But both incorrect, I don't know what they mean. And you are right, they may come from operating system, since I'm trying to run "cmd /C tsc hello.ts"

Comment: @Freewind: Are they not appropriate Chinese then? Or do you not understand Chinese (or the version on your particular system)?

Answer (score 8):

There are two parts to the answer.

1. Java displays error messages based on the default locale. There are three system properties which define the default locale: `user.language`, `user.country` and `user.variant`. If you have access to your Java VM command line you can set these properties using the `-D` command line switch. E.g. this is enough to switch Java to generic English:

   ```
   java -Duser.language=en com.my.Class
   ```
2. You can define a `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable and specify your options there. Any JVM starting in such environment will pick these options up as if they were on the command line.