# How do you troubleshoot sublime text 2 (typescript) build errors?

Tags: sublimetext2, typescript

I am using a typescript build from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779631/how-to-configure-a-sublime-build-system-for-typescript) along with a [build-on-save](https://github.com/alexnj/SublimeOnSaveBuild) plugin in sublime text 2 to try and get automatic typescript compiling:

```
{
    "cmd": ["tsc","$file"],
    "file_regex": "(.*\\.ts?)\\s\\(([0-9]+)\\,([0-9]+)\\)\\:\\s(...*?)$",
    "selector": "source.ts",
    "osx": {
       "path": "/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin"
    }
}
```

**It never builds because of the following error.** Any tips?

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'tsc', u'/Users/dbrito/Sites/Prototypes/totem-tracker/client/views/layout.ts']]
[dir:  /Users/dbrito/Sites/Prototypes/totem-tracker/client/views]
[path: /usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin]
[Finished]
```

Note: node and npm were installed using homebrew. Typescript was installed with `npm -g install typescript`. I'm on 10.8.2 with the latest xcode and command line tools installed. The following is in my `.profile`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/Library/Aliases:${PATH}"
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules:${NODE_PATH}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that either it can't find `tsc` or your file. can you double check the file shown in your error exists, and then give the output of `which tsc` in your terminal?

Is it outside your `/usr/local/bin`? Try removing the `osx` path setting thing.

Comment: What do you mean by "path setting thing." I would assume tsc is available in my path because the tsc command works. ```which tsc``` outputs ```/usr/local/share/npm/bin/tsc```, which I believe is the standard global npm location.

Comment: Right. Do you see in you example code how you have that part that says "osx":{"path":"..."}?

Comment: You are telling sublime text to look for tsc only in those folders. Remove it and I bet it will work. If not, replace with the path that which returns.

Comment: Looks like that may have brought me one step closer. Now the error is ```env: node: No such file or directory
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]```

Comment: It sounds like sublime doesn't respect your shell's path at all. Alright, try keeping the osx path thing, but put in the actual value of your path. I

Comment: You can get the value of your path with `echo $PATH` in terminal