# Typescript Build System Config in Sublime Text with --module option

Tags: node.js, sublimetext2, typescript

I tried with [these build system configs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779631/how-to-configure-a-sublime-build-system-for-typescript) but I wanna add the '--module commonjs' option to the compiler.

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
{
    "selector": "source.ts",
    "cmd": ["tsc.cmd","--module commonjs","$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(.*\\.ts?)\\s\\(([0-9]+)\\,([0-9]+)\\)\\:\\s(...*?)$"
}
```

error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'module commonjs'. I got this error. it's like is not recognizing the '--' characters

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where pretty close! If you change `--module commonjs` to separate items it works correctly, see below.

```
"cmd": ["tsc.cmd","--module", "commonjs","$file"],
```